# swift notification not triggering

Tags: swift, notifications

I'm new to notifications in swift and have setup the following in my AppDelegate.swift file. It runs and I get print output that the notifications are setup and do not error. I also get the permission ask for notifications, which I click yes to. I believe the interval notification I have should trigger in 20 seconds after launch. It does not trigger, this doesn't change if I'm in the app or have minimized the app. Note I am running in Simulator mode from XCODE. Why is my notification not triggering?

```
    func setupNotifications(){

        let notificationCenter = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()

        notificationCenter.requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .badge, .sound]) { (granted, error) in
            if granted {
                print("Yay!")
            } else {
                print("D'oh")
            }
        }

        notificationCenter.removeAllPendingNotificationRequests()
        print("setting up notifications")
        let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
        content.title = "Answer your daily questions"
        content.body = "Answer your daily questions please"
        content.categoryIdentifier = "alarm"
        content.userInfo = ["customData": "fizzbuzz"]
        content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default

        //let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: (1*60), repeats: true)
        let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: 20, repeats: false)

        // Create the request
        let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "daily-notifier",
                    content: content, trigger: trigger)

        // Schedule the request with the system.
        notificationCenter.add(request) { (error) in
           if error != nil {
            print("there were errors to address")
              // Handle any errors.
           }
        }
        print("done setting up notifications")
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        let path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.applicationSupportDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)
        print("\(path)")

        // Override point for customization after application launch.

        setupNotifications()  
        return true
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First note that you should probably wait to receive permission before adding a request for a local notification as per Apple's documentation of the `requestAuthorization(options:completionHandler:)`

> Note: Always call this method before scheduling any local notifications and before registering with the Apple Push Notification service.

Also make sure that you've added Push Notifications as a capability for your app as this will be needed should you submit it.

After I ran the above code I did not receive a notification while the app was still active but I did receive one while the app was in the background. I believe that if a user receives a notification for an app that is in the active state it is given silently; i.e., without the banner and sound (at least this is what I have experienced with my notifications, although there may be more to it).

Comment: no idea why you were voted down, just voted you up, very helpful, will look into that a bit later.

Comment: your right, it did trigger in the background after I set it up as a completion event. So if it triggers while the app is open anyway to catch / handle that?

Comment: Set a delegate for the notification center (conforming to the `UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate` protocol) by accessing the center's `delegate` property and use the `userNotificationCenter(_ center:willPresent: withCompletionHandler:)` method. This is called when the application is in the foreground.